# How do I transfer my messenger account to a new phone?

Tags: facebook

I am using messenger without facebook. How do I transfer my account to a new phone? The app on a new phone immediately asks me for a facebook account.

Comment: If you are talking about Facebook Messenger you should write that in your question.

Comment: Edit: I read your Messenger question as if it were about your text Messages. I don't know if Messenger texts are the same as text Messages. The below works on text Messages. (I don't have experience with Messenger.)

I used SMS Backup And Restore, the free version. It allows you to save the current instance of your Messages in a file on the old phone. Then email that file to yourself (or at least save it in some fashion). Then install SMS Backup And Restore on the new phone and restore the saved file from the older phone on the new phone.